# Webspher server ports not behaving as expected

Tags: websphere, admin, rad, ports

In WAS, the admin console is usually accessed at the url : `https://localhost:9043/console`. Now I just wanted to know where from this 9043 came about. So I go to `Servers--> Application Servers --> server1 --> Ports` and expect to see `9043` as one of the ports listed.  There is: `WC_adminhost : 9060` and `WC_adminhost_secure :9043`. So far so good.

My question is: if `https://localhost:9043/console` brings up the page, why does 
`http://localhost:9060/console` gives an error page?

Comment: what error does it give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the naming is a little confusing, but here is your answer. In order to get to admin console, there are two URLs:

```
http://localhost:9060/admin/ (shortened) 
http://localhost:9060/ibm/console
```

there are no page define as /console, so I would expect you to get 404.

Then if your server is secure, you are redirected to port 9043